# Joomla 5 translation for com_content category layout in custom template

Tags: joomla

I've created a template layout for com_content.category

```
/htdocs/templates/mytpl/html/com_content/category/mylayout.php|xml
```

and edited  section in *mylayout.xml* file. This works as expect if I create a new menu item.

But if I **edit a category** and select **options/layout** I see the filename ("mylayout") where Joomla's layouts have a proper name (Blog/List). https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Template_Layouts#Translation has a description how to "translate" your layouts but is missing an example for com_content.category. I've tried these languages strings without success:

```
TPL_MYTPL_COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY_LAYOUT_MYLAYOUT="My fancy layout"
TPL_MYTPL_COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY_VIEW_LAYOUT_MYLAYOUT="My fancy layout"
TPL_MYTPL_COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY_VIEW_MYLAYOUT="My fancy layout"
TPL_MYTPL_COM_CONTENT_LAYOUT_MYLAYOUT="My fancy layout"
```

Any hints?

(Joomla 5.0.2)